# Здраствуйте. Подскажите, что не так с кодом?

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно записать массив в таблицу `table_1`.
Одну запись в таблицу вносит без проблем... а вот если перебрать польностю массив, записи в таблицу не попадают

```
<?php

$arr = Array(
    Array(
        'first_name'=> 'Іра',
        'last_name'=> 'Ворза',
        'age'=> 35
    ),
    Array(
        'first_name'=> 'Петро',
        'last_name'=> 'Мазур',
        'age'=> 21
    ),
    Array(
        'first_name'=> 'Сергій',
        'last_name'=> 'Юхимов',
        'age'=> 31
    ),

    Array(
        'first_name'=> 'Ігор',
        'last_name'=> 'Добрий',
        'age'=> 22
    ),
    Array(
        'first_name'=> 'Олег',
        'last_name'=> 'Пархонов',
        'age'=> 20
    ),
    Array(
        'first_name'=> 'Станіслав',
        'last_name'=> 'Гетьман',
        'age'=> 33
    ),
);

foreach ($arr as $array1) {
    foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
        $k[] = $key;
        $v[] = "'".$value."'";
    }
}

$k = implode(", ", $k);
$v = implode(", ", $v);

$server_name = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "1";
$DB_name = "testDB";

$connection = new mysqli($server_name, $username, $password, $DB_name);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Error: ' . mysqli_connect_errno();
} else {
    echo "Connection created!";
    echo '<br>';
    echo
    "****************************************************************************************";
    echo '<br>';
}

$create_table = "CREATE TABLE `testDB`.`table_1` ( `first_name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
                 `last_name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , `age` INT(3) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;";

$create_table = mysqli_query($connection, $create_table);

$write_data = "INSERT INTO `table_1` ($k) VALUES($v)";
$write_data1 = mysqli_query($connection, $write_data);

$connection -> close();
```

Comment: Потому, что несколько строк одним запросом вставляются не так. https://php.ru/forum/threads/vstavka-v-bd-mysql-srazu-mnogo-zapisej.63831/

Comment: Или многими запросами, по циклу, в одной транзакции:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15149622/13578169